# Formatação GRID

Tags: css, html5, grid, flexbox

Eu to tentando fazer uma pagina com 4 elementos porem com um espaçamento mt especifico .
[image: Movimentar o botão laranja para a borda de baixo direita do elemento verde]

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 

    <style>
        body{
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left:0;
            margin-right: 0;
         
        }
        @font-face {
        font-family: 'Arson';
        src: url('Arson Pro Medium.otf') format('opentype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Arsonl';
        src: url('Arson Pro Light.otf') format('opentype');
        font-weight:bolder;
        font-style: bolder;
        font-size:larger

    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Arsonb';
        src: url('Arson Pro Black.otf') format('opentype');
        

    }
    @font-face{
    font-family: 'Arsonr';
        src: url('Arson Pro Regular.otf') format('opentype');
    }
    .cabeca{
        
        background-color: #d3d2d1;   
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        border: 0px;
    }
   
    .container-logo{
       margin-top: 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px; 
        padding-bottom: 10px;   
        width: auto;     
    }

    .h1{
        margin-top: 35px;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-style:normal;
        font-weight: 4777;
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-family: "Arsonr";
    }
    .vc{
        font-family: "Arsonr";
    }
    .negrito{
        font-family: "Arsonb";
    }
    .circulo{
        color: chocolate;
        
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .primeiracaixa:nth-child(1)
    {
        grid-row:1 / 3;
       
    border-radius: 10px;
    
  background-color:#a8a829 ;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;  
  border-width: 1px; 
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eeecea;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-family: "arsonr";
  
    }
.segundacaixa{
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color:#d2d2d3 ;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 120px;
  width: auto;  
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-width: 1px; 
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eeecea;
  font-family: "Arson";
  
} 
.segundacaixatexto{
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left:15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.icone{
    color: chocolate;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
 
}
.saibamais{
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-family: "arsonr";
    font-size: 10px;
}
.terceiracaixa{
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color:#dadbdb ;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;  
  border-width: 1px; 
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eeecea;
  font-family: "Arsonr";
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.terceiracaixatexto{
 font-family:"arson" ;
 
}
.quartacaixadetexto{
font-family: "arsonr";
}
.quintacaixadetexto{
    font-family: "arsonr";
}
.icone2{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;

}
.quartacaixa{
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    
    background-color: chocolate;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 250px;  
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;


}
.botao{
 font-family: "arson";
 text-align: center;

 padding-bottom: 10px;
 

}
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 780px 1fr  ;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: end;
    width: ;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
<header class="cabeca">

        <div class="container-logo">
          <div class="logo-imagens" ></div>
          <img src="#" alt="250" width="250" class="cabeca"></div>    
</header>
<section class="grid">

    <div class="primeiracaixa"  >
    <div><h1 class="h1"> TEXTO </h1>
    <p class="vc">TEXTO <span class="negrito">TEXTO</span>TEXTO</p>    
    <p><span class="circulo">●</span>TEXTO
    <p><span class="circulo">●</span>TEXTO</p>
    
    </div>
</div>




     
  

<div class="segundacaixa">
        <div class="segundacaixatesto"><ion-icon name="desktop-outline" class="icone"></ion-icon> TEXTO</div>
        <div class="saibamais">
          <a href="#" class="texto3caixa">TEXTO
          </a> 
        </div>
        
</div>
<div class="terceiracaixa"> 
    <div class="terceiracaixatexto"><img class="icone2" src="#" > TEXTO</div>
    <div class="quartacaixadetexto">TEXTO</div>
    <div class="quintacaixadetexto"> TEXTO</div>
    <div class="sextacaixadetexto"><span class="negrito">TEXTO</span>TEXTO</div>
    
    
</div>

<div class="quartacaixa">

   
    <div class="botao"></div>
    
</div>

</section>



</body>
















</html>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Creio que entendi seu questionamento e dê uma olhada no [link](https://www.origamid.com/projetos/css-grid-layout-guia-completo/) de referência para lhe ajudar, porém recomendo que procure entender o funcionamento do `display: grid` para trabalhar a vontade no css

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Para trabalhar com esse tipo de visualização, dê uma olhada no `display: grid` do css, onde consegue definir de forma apropriada e que lhe ajudará, inclusive, na responsividade desses elementos.

Segue link de referência para auxílio e maior personalização: [Link css display: grid](https://www.origamid.com/projetos/css-grid-layout-guia-completo/)

Para o caso que colocou, poderia ser algo próximo ao código abaixo, como não existe muita especificação em seu exemplo (e recomendo fortemente que veja para poder usufruir como precisar desse tipo de `display`):

```css
/* Grid */
.grid {
    display: grid;
}

.div1 {
    grid-area: div1;
    height: 270px;
}

.div2 {
    grid-area: div2;
    height: 150px;
}

.div3 {
    grid-area: div3;
    height: 130px;
}

.div4 {
    grid-area: div4;
    height: 250px;
}

.grid-template-areas-1 {
    grid-template-areas:
        "div1 div1 div2"
        "div1 div1 div4"
        "div3 div3 div4"
    ;
}

/* Grid Item */
.item {
    margin: 5px;
    background: tomato;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.grid {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: monospace;
    color: #333;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    margin: 0px;
}

body>div {
    padding: 40px 0;
}

body>div:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
}

body>div>img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Resultado</h1>
    <section class="grid grid-template-areas-1">
        <div class="item div1">Div 1</div>
        <div class="item div2">Div 2</div>
        <div class="item div3">Div 3</div>
        <div class="item div4">Div 4</div>
    </section>
</div>
```